# running jasmine specs with browsersync

Tags: node.js, jasmine, browser-sync

Is it possible to run jasmine spec selenium testcases using browser sync?

I am able to run simple html files using browsersync in nodejs. Is it possible to run jasmine specs using the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. BrowserSync is a tool to sync browsers, not to run tasks. Maybe you would like to take a look at a JS Task Runner such as http://gulpjs.com/ or http://gruntjs.com/

They can run jasmine, watch your files and run after changes (take a look at Karma too)

Answer (score 0):

`BrowserSync` is just tool that watches some specified files and serves them to the Browser every time a change has been made.

It's not a Task runners which handles different tasks through plugins that that do a task like Linting, Compiling, Testing and Serving.

Two such Popular TaskRunner app are Grunt and Gulp for Node.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "run": I load up my jasmine specs embedded within html runner files in my browser - and have browser-sync running in [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (a task runner that runs on node), via the [grunt-browser-sync](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/grunt/) plugin.  Any changes to either specs or source files are automatically reloaded - so my tests effectively get re-run every time I save a file, giving me instant test feedback on changes.

I'm not actually running selenium tests this way, but I don't see why this wouldn't work too.  The only issue I can see is the tests are likely to be slower, so you are likely to have to wait longer for the browser to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this in the Jasmine directory:

```
$ browser-sync start --files . --index SpecRunner.html --server
```